# Firebase Crashlytics on iOS "upload-symbols" not working / getting stuck

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to upload my dSYM using the following script

```
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
```

The script (running in debug mode) lists:

```
upload-symbols 3.8 build 27

Arguments:
Debug mode enabled
Google App ID: 1:y:ios:xx
Platform: ios
DSYM Paths: ["/Users/x/Downloads/appDsyms/xxx.dSYM/"]

Inspecting next path: /Users/x/Downloads/appDsyms/xxx.dSYM/
Found dSYM at path: /Users/x/Downloads/appDsyms/xxx.dSYM/
Begin processing dSYM at /Users/x/Downloads/appDsyms/xxx.dSYM
```

here it gets stuck with no output for hours.

This has worked fine up until recently. Now the script just gets stuck forever. No error message. I tried this a few days in a row (with restarts in between) and updated to the latest Firebase version. The same applies for my colleagues.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was: **re-download the AppDsyms.zip** from App Store Connect and then upload it again.

I suppose there was an error while uploading that has left the files in a corrupt state. After that, no upload was possible. This is why re-downloading the DSYMs fixed this issue.